# Overload invalid argument

Tags: c#, forms, overloading

Hi i'm brand new so don't judge to hard on my rookie question,

```
namespace Oef5_3_ShowIncome
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int YearSalary = Convert.ToInt32(YearSalaryTextBox.Text);
            int numberOfYears = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfYearsTextBox.Text);
            ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
            MessageBox.Show("something something ", Convert.ToString(ShowIncome)));
        }

        private int ShowIncome(int lalala, int dadada)
        {
            int results = lalala * dadada;
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

in... MessageBox.Show("something something "  Convert.ToString(ShowIncome)));
i receive the following error: the best overloaded method match for windows.form.messagebox.show(string, string) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: 11 questions, 0 accepted. [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Because ShowIncome is a method.  You might mean `MessageBox.Show("something something ", Convert.ToString(ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears))));`

Comment: mrName, you should go back to your previous questions and accept some answers. Look at the FAQ for instructions (or just pick one and click the large checkbox next to it.)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int YearSalary = Convert.ToInt32(YearSalaryTextBox.Text);
    int numberOfYears = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfYearsTextBox.Text);
    int showInCome = ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
    MessageBox.Show("something something ", showInCome.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line you are calling the method without saving the result to a variable

```
ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
```

What you want to do is this

```
int result = ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
```

And then pass result to the messagebox method

```
MessageBox.Show("something something ", result.ToString()));
```

Comment: and what if i would want to save a result into a variable and still see the result? for example in a ref or out?

Comment: What do you mean see the result?  out parameters pass the variable by reference so if you change it, it changes everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
int YearSalary = Convert.ToInt32(YearSalaryTextBox.Text);
        int numberOfYears = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfYearsTextBox.Text);
        ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
        MessageBox.Show("something something ", Convert.ToString(ShowIncome(100000, 5).ToString())));
```

because you called the method without passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you've confused the parser there I believe, it didn't know waht to do with ShowIncome as an argument

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int YearSalary = Convert.ToInt32(YearSalaryTextBox.Text);
            int numberOfYears = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfYearsTextBox.Text);
            int income = ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);
            MessageBox.Show("something something ", Convert.ToString(income));
        }
```

or

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int YearSalary = Convert.ToInt32(YearSalaryTextBox.Text);
            int numberOfYears = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfYearsTextBox.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("something something ", Convert.ToString(ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears)));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're not passing any arguments in to ShowIncome, so you're effectively trying to call Convert.ToString on a methodgroup.

Comment: but YearSalary, numberOfYears becomes lalala & dadada right? (i just took some stupid random names) and if you try to return it back in a string for you messagebox it should normally work, i think..

Comment: @mrName I'm not really following what you are saying.  This: Convert.ToString(ShowIncome) is not going to work and is obscuring the real error since its inline.  It won't return a string since there is no Convert.ToString overload that takes a methodgroup as its lone param, hence the error you're seeing.  If you called Convert.ToString(ShowIncome(someint, someint)) or whatever integers you want to pass in, then yeah, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone i thank you all thrully with all my hard, ive learned 2 new ways if i have this same error again how to bypass that error, such as using a ...result.ToString, or even give their own arguments as result.tostring(1000,500);

But i've seen the solution to my problem if i create a variable for example
int something = ShowIncome(YearSalary, numberOfYears);

MessageBox.Show("yay random words lalala " + Convert.ToString(something));

then it works somehow, i wish i knew why